# using date ranges and numbers

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2011, worksheet-function

I have a spreadsheet that uses both dates and numbers. For example I have a job that takes 4 hours to complete and needs to be done on 10/11/13. I have several jobs that end on this date but the time to complete them are different. Then I have other jobs that end on 10/18/13 etc. The jobs I have listed need updates on them each Friday. Here's what I need. I need a formula that adds hours for a certain dates, how many hours are needed for jobs ending on 10/11/13 etc. We have a spreadsheet that list jobs and dates through the end of the year.

Comment: This question is pretty unclear, especially as you've tagged it array formulas, but you haven't mentioned your data layout at all.  Some sample data, columns,  or example calculations would probably make this much clearer.

Comment: Dates on Excel are represented by numbers (days counting from Jan 1, 1900), this might be helpful, as you would need to add 4/24 to increase a date by 4 hours.

Answer (score 1):

Add hours to date.

> =A1+B1/24

A1 is your date and time, B1 is your hours you're adding to the date and time in A1

Hours needed.

> =INT((A4-B4)*24)

A4 is given date (10/12/2013 12:00AM), B4 is the current date and time "=NOW()"